# Storing an integer array in a string variable using shell scripting

Tags: shell

I have been trying to store an integer array in a variable as a string using Unix  shell scripting.

e.g.:

```
int array[2]={0,1,2}
```

as

```
str="123"
```

How may I accomplish this?

Comment: More of a functional question, but do you want this string to store numbers greater than `9`? I imagine if `array[3] = {9, 10, 11}`, `str = "91011"` could become a problem.

Comment: You haven't been doing anything with **arrays** in Unix shell scripting, maybe in bash or zsh, but not POSIX shell (it doesn't have arrays...) Please choose the correct tag, e.g. `bash` or `zsh` or `ksh` to match the shell you are actually using.

Comment: Further, please clarify your question. You are attempting to assign, depending on your shell, a *brace-expansion* of `{0,1,2}` (e.g. `012` which should be quoted to avoid confusion) to the second element of `array`, (e.g. `array[2]="012"`) and then you are asking how to turn that into `str=123`?? Huh?? There appears to be either a typo or a logical disconnect somewhere... or do you really want to add `+1` to each digit in `array[2]` to arrive at `str`?

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following and at the end str will store the entire array as string:

```
Arr=(1,2,3)
$ echo ${Arr}
1,2,3

str=`echo "${Arr//,}"`
$ echo $str
123
```

Comment: I see where you are going. Always put `4-spaces` in front of your code to format your code (as code) in your answer. Also, how did you get `Arr=(1,2,3)` to be equivalent to `array[2]={0,1,2}`? You create a single element array `Arr[0]="1,2,3"` where the original had `array[2]={0,1,2}`. You then use normal variable notation with guards  (e.g. `${var}`) to access the first element of `Arr`??  I'm not sure the question is clear enough to answer at this point, but your answer may benefit from further explanation.